# Grub won't make on Cygwin

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, grub

It seems that information about using the two together is not easy to come by. When trying to make I get some fun errors. I was wondering if my version of gcc (4.7) won't cut it or I'm lacking a dependency.

I included...

- GCC
- GNU Make
- GNU Bison
- GNU gettext
- GNU binutils
- Flex

Am doubtful about but am beginning to wonder if it matters

- libdevmapper

The error that occurs in Cygwin x86 - Possibly GCC 4.7 related?

```
../grub-2.00/grub-core/lib/xzembed/xz_dec_lzma2.c:534:29: error: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Werror=attributes]
```

Comment: That's a warning that's being promoted to an error because the build uses -Werror. Turn that off and you'll be able to continue. I do wonder what you plan to do with a Linux bootloader in a Windows application...

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the problem appears to have something to do with header sizes being larger than expected. The issue is related to this problem:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2013-12/msg00342.html

Do this:

```
export TARGET_CFLAGS="-Qn"
```

...and rebuild from a fresh grub-2.00 source directory. That should fix things up.